# Menu title in Keyboard Shortcuts?

Tags: keyboard, mail.app, keybindings

I recently started using the Mac mail app. I like to keep the inbox clean and so I want to move every message that I read to a Backup folder ( not Archive for some very silly reason! ).

So, I decided to create a shortcut using `System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts`.

> When I try to add a shortcut, I have to fill a field named **Menu Title** where I have to write **exact name of the menu command** but how would I know which commands the Mail app knows about?

So, my question is **How to know about menu commands that an app accepts on Mac?**

Comment: those are all shown in the mail menu it self, so look which one you want to have

Comment: I want to move it to a specific folder in mail (marked as on My Mac)?

Comment: maybe this is what you would like, Open mail > Preferences > Rules .. try it if you like it, I use it to keep , my mail organized and other actions.

Comment: Ah! this is some very good stuff. Thanks for telling me about this! However, I am not able to create a rule for messages that are read :(

Comment: you do not mark message as Read! it will do that automatically as you click on it, however you can mark it as unread if you are not done reading it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mac Mail is highly customisable to individual needs.

I like to keep it organized by using Mail Rules.

I created folders in Mail (on my Mac) named Bank, Utility, Phone, and many others.

Then in Mail > Preferences > Rules I set up so that if a mail arrives from one of those, it will be moved to the appropriate folder, and I will not miss it. (It shows in particular folder as unread as long I did not read it.

I also have rules set up to Delete some emails from specific sources. The combinations are almost endless what you can do to keep your Mail organized.

Mail Rules is the way to go, no need to create new keyboard shortcuts.

Example..for Sprint Phone emails..

[image]

You do not have to type they email address, just select it in Mail before creating the rule and it will show up.

One more trick. For some of us we want the mail to remain as Unread  till we say so (and do not want the automated mail feature marking them as read as soon we touch it).

To do so just drag the mail "Preview window" down till it disperses and mails will remain Unread till we tell it otherwise.

Comment: Thanks! Not only you told me what menu titles are, you also introduced me to "Rules" in mail.

Comment: @scipsycho  you are welcome ! do not hesitate to come back with more questions.